# there is no attribute "data-cfasync" (Olark) WP

Tags: wordpress, validation, plugins, widget

Since adding the code to use Olark: http://www.olark.com/

I get a validation error of

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type='text/javascript'>/*<![CDATA[*/window.olark||…
✉
You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).

This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error message for further information.
```

the doctype is transitional. How do i got about fixing this?

It also has a  in the code which throws up the following error:

```
The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").
```

Answer (score 5):

Sunir from Olark here. You can remove that attribute for your website. It's used to manage an interaction with Cloudflare. If you're not using Cloudflare, it's not required.

http://blog.cloudflare.com/combining-javascript-css-a-better-way

Comment: Which attribute are you referring to specifically? It seems the error is caused by the use of `<!CDATA` in the script element.

Comment: He meant the "data-cfasync" attribute.